# Determining whether a file struct (Describing a file descriptor) is a 'special file' (i.e. block/character device)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have modified the system-call table such that my own mmap handler will be called upon a user-space call to mmap.
My handler calls the original mmap and according to the result chooses what to do.

Here's a very short code snippet:

```
asmlinkage unsigned long my_mmap_handler(unsigned long addr,
                                     unsigned long len,
                                     int prot,
                                     int flags,
                                     int fd,
                                     long off)
{
     unsigned long ret_val = old_mmap(addr,len,prot,flags,fd,off);
     if (IS_ERR((void*)ret_val))
         goto end;
     // Do some stuff..
     end:
     return ret_val;
}
```

while in "Do some stuff" I do some operations on the actual mapped file (i.e. reading from the file).

Here's the problem:

I have encountered programs that try to mmap character/block devices (e.g. /dev/rdi/card0). Whenever I try to read (e.g. using vfs_read) from such a file, the kernel freezes (Not a panic, but it feels like something is blocking). Why exactly does that happen?
Anyway, I don't need to perform operations on character/block devices so I've been trying to find a way of finding out if a given 'struct file' represents a block/character device and in case it is just ignore it. No luck so far.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for [`man fstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the preprocessor macro:

```
 #define special_file(m) (S_ISCHR(m)||S_ISBLK(m)||S_ISFIFO(m)||S_ISSOCK(m))

 defined in linux/fs.h
```

The macro can be then used as follows to determine whether a file pointer 'describes' a special file:

```
struct file * f;
// ...
if (special_file(file_inode(f)->i_mode))
{
     /* If we're here then it is a
     block/character device or FIFO/SOCKET file */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if a file is a block or character device by reading it's inode structure member i_rdev:

```
file->f_dentry->d_inode->i_rdev
```

It contains the major,minor value and if it's not 0 it's a device